# How to upload android app have content 16+

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application. My app have content about jokes or funny photo.
However some jokes or photo have content only fit for adult persion (16+)

I want to know How do I upload this app to Google Play.

Comment: Did you try uploading it first of all?

Comment: My app not video or naked sex, I think I can upload it when setup corect.